# How to add Scrollbar to View Flipper in android

Tags: android, scrollbar, viewflipper

I want to add a scroll bar to the ViewFlipper at the bottom to indicate the page flow in android. how to do it. Is there any library/method available to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by default. but, we can use support libraries from github for doing that. Use UnderlinePageIndicator of [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) for displaying scrollbar indicator in bottom of the ViewPager and use UnderlinePageIndicator of [Android-ViewFlipperIndicator](https://github.com/kevintanhongann/Android-ViewFlipperIndicator) for displaying scrollbar indicator in bottom of the ViewFlipper.

In Layout file: Add the indicator below the pager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

In Activity/Fragment: Add this indicator to pager after creating its reference

```
ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.pager);
UnderlinePageIndicator mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById (R.id.indicator);
mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```

Similar approach for ViewFlipper as well